# chef error Chef::Util::FileEdit

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I have following `ruby_block` in chef cookbook

```
ruby_block "hosts" do
  block do
    rc = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/login.defs")
    rc.search_file_replace_line(
      /^PASS_MAX_DAYS   99999$/,
      "PASS_MAX_DAYS   150"
    )
    rc.write_file
  end
end
```

when i run chef-client i am getting following error

```
 * ruby_block[hosts] action run[2014-11-20T18:35:17+00:00] INFO: Processing ruby_block[hosts] action run (my_cookbook::default line 31)


    ================================================================================
    Error executing action `run` on resource 'ruby_block[hosts]'
    ================================================================================

    ArgumentError
    -------------
    invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII

    Cookbook Trace:
    ---------------
    /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'

    Resource Declaration:
    ---------------------
    # In /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb

     31: ruby_block "hosts" do
     32:   block do
     33:     rc = Chef::Util::FileEdit.new("/etc/login.defs")
     34:     rc.search_file_replace_line(
     35:       /^PASS_MAX_DAYS   99999$/,
     36:       "PASS_MAX_DAYS   150"
     37:     )
     38:     rc.write_file
     39:   end
     40: end
     41:

    Compiled Resource:
    ------------------
    # Declared in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb:31:in `from_file'

    ruby_block("hosts") do
      action "run"
      retries 0
      retry_delay 2
      guard_interpreter :default
      block_name "hosts"
      cookbook_name "my_cookbook"
      recipe_name "default"
      block #<Proc:0x000000024e8cc8@/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb:32>
    end

[2014-11-20T18:35:17+00:00] INFO: Running queued delayed notifications before re-raising exception

Running handlers:
[2014-11-20T18:35:17+00:00] ERROR: Running exception handlers
Running handlers complete
[2014-11-20T18:35:17+00:00] ERROR: Exception handlers complete
[2014-11-20T18:35:17+00:00] FATAL: Stacktrace dumped to /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Chef Client failed. 0 resources updated in 1.322765293 seconds
[2014-11-20T18:35:17+00:00] ERROR: ruby_block[hosts] (my_cookbook::default line 31) had an error: ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
[2014-11-20T18:35:17+00:00] FATAL: Chef::Exceptions::ChildConvergeError: Chef run process exited unsuccessfully (exit code 1)
```

Just for testing i have edit `/etc/hosts` file entry using above code and it works! look like `/etc/login.defs` has something wired

## chef-stacktrace.out

```
root@node04:/etc# cat /var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out
Generated at 2014-11-20 18:51:45 +0000
ArgumentError: ruby_block[hosts] (my_cookbook::default line 31) had an error: ArgumentError: invalid byte sequence in US-ASCII
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/util/editor.rb:79:in `match'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/util/editor.rb:79:in `match'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/util/editor.rb:79:in `block in replace_lines'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/util/editor.rb:78:in `map!'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/util/editor.rb:78:in `replace_lines'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/util/file_edit.rb:46:in `search_file_replace_line'
/var/chef/cache/cookbooks/my_cookbook/recipes/default.rb:34:in `block (2 levels) in from_file'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/ruby_block.rb:33:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/ruby_block.rb:33:in `block in action_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/mixin/why_run.rb:52:in `add_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider.rb:156:in `converge_by'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider/ruby_block.rb:32:in `action_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/provider.rb:121:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource.rb:648:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:49:in `run_action'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block (2 levels) in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `each'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:81:in `block in converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:98:in `block in execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:116:in `call_iterator_block'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:85:in `step'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:104:in `iterate'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection/stepable_iterator.rb:55:in `each_with_index'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/resource_collection.rb:96:in `execute_each_resource'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/runner.rb:80:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:345:in `converge'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:431:in `do_run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:213:in `block in run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `fork'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/client.rb:207:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application.rb:236:in `run_chef_client'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:338:in `block in run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `loop'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application/client.rb:327:in `run_application'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/lib/chef/application.rb:55:in `run'
/opt/chef/embedded/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/chef-11.16.4/bin/chef-client:26:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/bin/chef-client:23:in `load'
```

Comment: Please include the full traceback from `/var/chef/cache/chef-stacktrace.out`.

Comment: Update my question with `chef-stacktrace.out` if i remove everything from that `login.defs` and just keep `PASS_MAX_DAYS` line then it works! do you think because of filesize its not working

Comment: No, you just have non-ASCII content in the file, and FileEdit can't cope with that as written. You could either improve FileEdit to correctly handle multibyte encodings or not use it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

FileEdit as written can't handle multibyte encodings. You can either fix FileEdit and submit a patch to Chef, or just not use it. Easiest solution is to convert all of `login.defs` to a `cookbook_file` or `template` resource, thus removing the need for FileEdit.

Comment: i don't know how to fix `multibyte encodings`, I am not ruby expert . can you help me with that?

Comment: I don't think SO likes advertising commercial services, so if this is in the context of free help then no I cannot since its not a simple fix.

Comment: Can I detect if file encoded with multibyte encoding? So then I know that I can use `FileEdit` in a code

Answer (score 2):

Though its too late. But just, if anyone came here searching for solution for this kind of issue.

```
file '/etc/login.defs' do
   action :create
   owner 'root'
   group 'root'
   mode '0644'
   content File.read("/etc/login.defs").gsub(/^PASS_MAX_DAYS\t99999$/, "PASS_MAX_DAYS\t150")
end
```

Kitchen Test run:-

```
     * file[/etc/login.defs] action create
       - update content in file /etc/login.defs from 11fa3a to 3d7172
       --- /etc/login.defs  2014-02-12 14:03:08.000000000 +0000
       +++ /etc/.chef-login.defs20160805-12038-orbb2x   2016-08-05 11:09:40.007822562 +0000
       @@ -22,7 +22,7 @@
        #   PASS_MIN_LEN    Minimum acceptable password length.
        #   PASS_WARN_AGE   Number of days warning given before a password expires.
        #
       -PASS_MAX_DAYS   99999
       +PASS_MAX_DAYS   150
        PASS_MIN_DAYS   0
        PASS_MIN_LEN    5
        PASS_WARN_AGE   7
       - restore selinux security context
```

Answer (score 0):

The [line cookbook](https://github.com/sous-chefs/line-cookbook) is typically what we recommend.

The approach that @mrigesh-priyadarshi uses in his answer to read the file, do the string substitution and then pass it as content to the file provider, is also perfectly acceptable.

Which one to use probably comes down personal preference, and the complexity and subjective readability of either approach.

The `Chef::Util::FileEdit` approach above is not only poor for multibyte encodings but the ruby_block will fire every time and is not idempotent and it would not be possible to chain a notification off of it that would only fire if the file contents were actually changed.